# Reading multiple CSV files from multiple folders in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have multiple folders and each folder have multiple .csv files, in this my code i read multiple files in one folder .
 so i am asking how can i read all folders(with its contents) one after another ?

```
inputpath = 'C:/Users/lap/Desktop/main/folder1/file*_com.csv'
    for file in iglob(inputpath):
        size = os.path.getsize(file) 
        si = size/1024
        print("size =', si)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle multiple files in multiple folders to `n` depth is [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk). I'd also recommend using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to handle all files and paths where possible.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os

input_path = Path(Path.home(), "Desktop", "main")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
    for file in (f for f in files if f.endswith("_com.csv")):
        file_path = Path(root, file)
        print(f"{file_path.name}, size = {file_path.stat().st_size/1024} KiB")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed, but can I read a specific file name in these folders (for example file*_com.csv')?